# How to create a function available in all opencart controllers?

Tags: opencart

I always use:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

I know I can create the following function

```
function v($results){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($results);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

But I don't know how can I make it available in all controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleanest way, imo would be to include something in `/system/startup.php` in the helper block:

```php
// Helper
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'helper/my_functions.php');
```

Then make a new php file `/system/helper/my_functions.php` and add your custom functions there and they will be available sitewide in both admin and front end.  It would also be a good idea to check and make sure the function doesn't already exist to be on the safe side:

```php
if (!function_exists('v')) {
    function v($results){
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($results);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

This should work on any version of Opencart.